# Export Data to PDF in ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, export, pdf-generation

In My ASP.NET Website, I am taking data inputs and storing it in Database. Now, I need to put a functionality where I can get the stored data in Export to PDF facility where i can save the pdf, having the data in specific format. Can anyone guide in this regard ?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use a 3rd party framework to do this. Most reporting tools have an option to export a report to PDF. I believe SSRS has this option, I know Crystal Reports has this functionality. I'm sure other reporting tools have this feature too.

There are also tools for directly generating PDFs instead of going through a report. A quick google search `of .net pdf generator` will be a good starting point. There is also iText which is an open source project for generating PDFs from xml. There is not much documentation on iText sharp and it's not actively developed from my understanding so expect a huge learning curve with this library.

unless the reporting features built into the .net framework (reporting services) can generate a PDF that meets your needs expect to purchase a 3rd party tool to help you create the PDF.

Comment: I have tried using third party services like pdfcrowd.com and http://www.web2pdfconvert.com but all they are not able to convert css/gridviews/templates in pdf. only outer html content is getting saved in pdf. Is there any tool which can convert the page irrespective of the mark up to pdf ?

Comment: what you describe: gridviews/templates, are server side webforms controls. no PDF generator will work with this controls directly. Instead pdf generators will work with xml and convert the xml into a PDF. HTML is a specific form of xml. How well a generator can translate the css & html will depend on the tool used. I would start  by searching for .net pdf generators: https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+pdf+generator